# How to limit a query on Event based on Opportunity standard field - StageName

Tags: apex, soql, query, opportunity, event

In the below query, I am trying to extract all Events that have a Opportunity of record type Id = 012240000002Cu8. I also want to further restrict this query based on the opportunity's stage

**My query:**

```
Select Id,X1st_booked_meeting__c, whatId FROM Event where what.recordtypeId = '012240000002Cu8'
```

**What I am trying to achieve:**

```
Select Id,X1st_booked_meeting__c, whatId FROM Event where what.recordtypeId = '012240000002Cu8' AND what.StageName!='Order Processed' AND what.StageName!= 'Closed Lost'.
```

`what.StageName` is throwing an error saying :

> No such column 'StageName' on entity 'Name'. If you are attempting to
>   use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field
>   name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the
>   appropriate names.

Here `StageName` is standard picklist field on opportunity.
`what.StageName` or `whatId.Stagename` does not seem to work.

I would like to know if this is possible?

Comment: See [Understanding Polymorphic Keys and Relationships](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_polymorph_keys.htm) for some background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in one soql-query without not needed loops:

```
[
    select Id,X1st_booked_meeting__c, WhatId
    from Event
    where WhatId in (
        select Id
        from Opportunity
        where RecordTypeId = '012240000002Cu8'
            and StageName != 'Order Processed' 
            and StageName != 'Closed Lost'
        )
]
```

PS. Hardcoding ids in code is a bad practice.

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution, It worked great. And I am using this query in data loader to fetch the records and not using it inside my code..

Answer (score 4):

Since you can not directly query this on Event as your what Id can be any object. What you can do is first query the opportunity

```
 List<Opportunity> opp = [select Id from Opportunity where RecordTypeId = '012240000002Cu8' AND StageName != 'Order Processed' AND StageName != 'Closed Lost'];
List<Id> oppId = new List<Id>();
for(Opportunity op : opp){
   oppId.add(op.Id);
}
```

Then query your Event based on this

```
Select Id,X1st_booked_meeting__c, whatId FROM Event where whatId IN : OppId
```